# Pro file directive: copy target to folder at build step

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a `TEMPLATE = subdirs` project with 6 subprojects which build in specified order.

I would like to copy the output file of project1 (it's target) to some folder.
This folder is passed with `LIBS += -L` to `project2` and `project2` may use this file as a static library.

I found some `.pro` file commands to copy target files wherever but they are performed at deploy step. I need this to be done at build step. Precisely after `project1` got built and before `project2` build starts. And would be better if that will be some code that could be kept in `.pro` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create DestDir.pri in folder, where all of your projects located. 
Insert next code:

```
isEmpty(DESTDIR) {
        CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
            DESTDIR=$$PWD/Build/Debug
        }

        CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
            DESTDIR=$$PWD/Build/Release
        }
}
```

Include DestDir.pri to each pro file:

```
include(../DestDir.pri)
```

You can change DESTDIR variable to your path or set this variable via qmake command line utils - in both cases this code will locate your artefacts to common folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [one more](http://dragly.org/2013/11/05/copying-data-files-to-the-build-directory-when-working-with-qmake/) way to achieve that:

```
copydata.commands = $(COPY_FILE) $$OUT_PWD/$(TARGET0) ~/my_libs/
first.depends = $(first) copydata
export(first.depends)
export(copydata.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first copydata
```

It allows to control what library file (.so, .so.1, .so.1.0, .so.1.0.0) is copied and seems to be crossplatform, so I'll left it here too.

But I'll use Milovidov's solution as less complicated in my project.